# Database queries to 'cache' are not allowed in this test in django 2.2

Tags: django, django-2.2

I'm migrating project to django 2.2 from django 1.11.
We have database based cache  that runs on different database (not on default).
When running tests, we get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Database queries to 'cache' are not allowed in this test. Add 'cache' to users.tests.UserLogTestCase.databases to ensure proper test isolation and silence this failure.
```

Adding the 'cache' database to the databases variable of the TestCase solves the problem (or setting it to '`__all__`'), the problem is that this has to be done per test.

Is there any other (more global) way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this problem.  In my environment I gave up long ago and inherit all test cases from a common class, `MyTestCase`.  I add the features in with mixins:

```
class MyTestCase(django.test.TestCase, ViewTestMixin, AssertResponseStatusMixin, CustomAssertions):

    pass


class MyAPITestCase(rest_framework.test.APITestCase, ViewTestMixin, AssertResponseStatusMixin, CustomAssertions, RedisClearMixin):

    pass
```

I add the `databases` variable to these base classes to apply globally.